# Regarding Multisampling of textures

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader, multisampling

i am rendering white cube with green background in non default FBO and attaching the created multisampled texture to this FBO.
When i render a cube in default FBO using above texture, it gives corruption in texture.

Here is my code:

```
viewport_width=32;
viewport_height=32;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureId);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glBindTexture(*target, textureId);"));     

        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"tk_diffuseMap"), 0);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,\"basetexture\"), 0);"));

        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4 ,GL_RGBA, viewport_width, viewport_height ,true);  
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4 ,GL_RGBA, 32, 32,true);"));       

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, Fboid);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Fboid);"));

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,textureId,0);    
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,textureId,0);"));

        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);"));

        draw_cube(viewport_width, viewport_height);

                glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Fboid);"));

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureId);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glBindTexture(*target, textureId);"));     

                glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, 36,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices );
```

fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2DMS tk_diffuseMap;
in vec3 ps_texCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{

    vec2 iTmp = textureSize(tk_diffuseMap);
    vec2 tmp = iTmp * ps_texCoord.xy;

    vec4 color;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        color = color + texelFetch(tk_diffuseMap, ivec2(tmp), i);
    }

fragColor=vec4(color/4);
}
```

Let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A texture used as a FBO's render target attachment *must not* be bound as sampling source if the FBO it is attached to, is bound as rendering target as well. It's either texture being bound or FBO being bound.

It's obvious why this must be the case: If you could bind a texture which is also a render target you'd create a circular dependency loop.

Comment: How can i solve the issue? because if i want to use different FBO in above code then i need to bind it to another texture and so on..
is there any alternative?

Comment: @Roshan: Use 2 textures in a round robin arrangement.

Comment: Can you please give some steps explaining which texture to bound which FBO and which to be sampled?

Comment: @Roshan: I suggest you first understand regular FBO render to texture before trying to implement a feedback loop (that's what you're trying to do). I have a minimal FBO example hosted at https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo

Comment: Saw your code, i think i am correctly using render to texture concept here. i am calling glTexImage2DMultisample instead of glTexImage2D as i want to use multisampling here and assuming that texture data will come from non default FBO.